# Is there a way for a contract to sign a transaction on the behalf of a user?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I want to know if its possible to allow a contract to vote on a snapshot space using the balance of the contract as it's voting weight. As of now I can only get an EOA to sign the transaction / vote on proposals. I was wondering if I could 'delegate' this signing power to a contract instead.
I know that contracts cant sign transactions since they have no private key however what is the best workaround for this.

For context I would like to build an app that allows users to stake Token A on contract A, which would allocate the given number of governance token to contract A (from contract B for example), then contract A could be used to vote off chain on snapshot.

Comment: What happens when you try?